# Reuse a ClearCase view

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I would like to reload a view (which was created previously) instead of creating a whole new one.

Two scenarios:

1 - Hard drive crashes and the local view isn't there anymore.
2 - A new laptop is set up with ClearCase.

In either (or both) of these cases, can a view be restored on your local drive?  Or does the view have to be removed and then create a new one?  I would rather not have STREAM_2_int and STREAM_3_int if I can get away from that.

(Side question:  If someone has a desktop and a laptop, can they use the same view on each, or is it only one for each computer?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for a snapshot view, provided the ClearCase view storage (the `.vws` directory) isn't on the same workstation than the view itself.

The only file needed to make a directory a root directory of a (previously created) snapshot view is the hidden file **`view.dat`**.

See the IBM technote "[Regenerate the `view.dat` file](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21204161)"

And the perl script (packaged within any ClearCase installation) used to restore that view.dat file is `<ClearCase>\etc\utils\regen_view_dot_dat.pl -tag <view-tag-id> <view root directory path>`.

Example:

```
C:\source>ccperl c:\Rational\ClearCase\etc\utils\regen_view_dot_dat.pl -tag aSnapViewName .
rgy_view_uuid: "d17190d381de4ce89757d5465eb41f2c".
creating ".\view.dat".

C:\source>type view.dat
ws_oid:00000000000000000000000000000000 view_uuid:d17190d381de4ce89757d5465eb41f2c
```

Again, that can only work if the view storage `\\shared\path\to\aSnapViewName.vws` is in a shared path accessible from the workstation or from the new laptop.

Comment: It seems to create the view.dat in "\\shared\path\to\aSnapViewName.vws\view.dat" and not on my local drive.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Rubasu yes, I have fixed this error: the second argument of the perl script is the path where to generate the `view.dat`. I have added a reference to the official IBM technote for more details on that process.